# For loop not executing;

Tags: java, for-loop

My code is not working for this method, I am trying to add up the sum of the sum of the numbers; if n = 3, return 10; n =6, return 56;

this is my code:

```
public int sumOfSums(int n) {
    int[] numArray = new int[n];
    int totalSum = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++){
        numArray[i] = n;
        n--;
        System.out.println(numArray[i]);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        totalSum += numArray[j];
        System.out.println("I am in for loop");
  if (j == n-1){
            j = 0;
            counter++;
        }
        if (counter == n){
            return totalSum;
        }

}
return totalSum;
}
```

Also total sum is not being assigned, this is the error I get:

```
----jGRASP exec: java -ea HazMath
-37337 is not prime
1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError
    at HazMath.main(HazMath.java:133)

 ----jGRASP wedge: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

from running this assert:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    HazMath HM=new HazMath();
        assert !HM.isPrime(3);
        assert !HM.isPrime(-37337);
        assert HM.sumOfSums(1) == 1;
    assert HM.sumOfSums(3) == 10;
    assert HM.sumOfSums(6) == 56;
    assert HM.sumOfSums(25) == 2925;
    assert HM.sumOfSums(-5) == 0;
    System.out.println("All tests passed.  VICTORY!");
    }
```

Comment: Acording to the error message, the `sumOfSums` does not actually get called, because an assertion is failing one line above.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please indent your code properly so we can read it. Your IDE can do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You are asserting on Prime which threw AssertionError. In case you intend to continue with the remaining tests, you will need to catch the Error.

Example code:

```
        try {
            assertTrue(hm.isPrime(-37337));
        }
        catch (AssertionError e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Further, if you are worried about your code not entering the second loop, then it is because of the following:

In the first loop, you are decrementing the value of n to 0.

And then you are comparing if 0 is less than 0 in the second loop.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but you can calculate the sum of sums more directly and avoid your loops by using the formula:

```
f(n) = n(n+1)(n+2) / 6
```

Rewriting your code to use this function will likely fix your issue in the process.